# What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?

Tags: macos, unicode, utf-8

What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?
I thought it was the difference between \n and \r(MAC OS 9) at first.
But I tried `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8-MAC filename > filename2`
The file content doesn't change in hex view.

Comment: It doesn't change in text view because the two version are (supposed to be) rendered the same.

Comment: @WGroleau I was talking about hex view not text view

Comment: Sorry—my eyes must be going.  I was sure I saw "text view."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As explained [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::UTF8Mac), utf-8-mac is the utf 8 version of a text after application of Unicode normalization NFD (e.g accented characters are represented by the base character plus a combining accent character), with certain codepoint ranges excluded from the decomposition operation.

For example character é can be represented in two different equally valid ways in Unicode:

- "\x{00E9}" - single codepoint, LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, utf-8 C3 A9, "composed".
- "\x{0065}\x{0301}" - two codepoints, LATIN SMALL LETTER E and COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT, utf-8 65 CC 81, "decomposed"

UTF-8-MAC will ensure that the second, decomposed form is always used.

Comment: Note that iconv seems to consistently quit with "unable to convert" when it reaches somewhere between 3900 and 4100 bytes into the file.  For several alternatives, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/448408/conversion-script-for-unicode-combining-characters?noredirect=1#comment648652_448408

Comment: To normalize using `uconv` [check this related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90164/209677)

Comment: For official Apple docs on this conversion see the (archived) [QA1173](https://web.archive.org/web/20100527091633/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1173.html)