# Conversion script for Unicode combining characters?

Tags: file-conversion, unicode

I have Greek text that used combining characters for all accented letters.  Some process that I was using with it converted these automatically to the single character equivalent.  This causes a problem for me in that I need the two versions to match in another app.  Or at least to sort into the same order.

I can hunt for one at a time and use find/replace to fix that one, but this is rather tedious.

**Is there a simple way to convert all of them?**  I can't do the original the way the second version was done, because they are different file types.

Comment: `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8-MAC filename > filename2` should do the trick, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/346453/30895

Comment: Looks like that will work, thanks.  (Though going the other way is better, because the actual filenames are composed form.)

Comment: So you want to convert from decomposed to composed form?

Comment: Either way, but composed is better.  iconv definitely can do either, but it seems to have a buffering problem—in large files, it stops and complains somewhere between 3950 & 4020 bytes.  But when the alleged "unable to convert line" is near the beginning of the file, it is converted with no problem.  A nine-hundred-line file had to be done in half-a-dozen sections.  Looks like you have the answer.

Comment: I'd be surprised if BBEdit couldn't handle this.

Comment: @benwiggy: You are right, BBEdit has a “Text -> Precompose Unicode” function. It would be interesting to know if that can be called from the command line for scripting.

Comment: BBEdit “Text -> Precompose Unicode” is something I'll also try‒open a big file in BBEdit and try that to see if it fails to finish as iconv does.

Comment: @WGroleau: I have tested BBEdit, iconv, uconv, Perl, and Swift with a 400K file. Only iconv failed for some input.

Comment: @benwiggy: Perhaps you want to add that as an answer? Comments may go unnoticed or be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some options to convert all decomposed Unicode characters into their precomposed form. I'll assume that the files are encoded in UTF-8.

#### iconv

`iconv` is a character set conversion tool (based on the [`iconv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/iconv.h.html) codeset conversion functions). On macOS, it supports the "UTF-8-MAC" encoding for decomposed UTF-8 characters (see [What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346453/what-the-difference-and-usage-of-encodings-utf-8-and-utf-8-mac-in-iconv)).

Usage:

```
iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8 < decomposed.txt > composed.txt
```

I found that `iconv` has problems with characters outside of the basic multilingual plane (emojis, flags, ...). As an example, it can not convert the characters  or . The following solutions do not have that problem.

#### Perl

A simple Perl script (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23159081/1187415) on Stack Overflow) can convert decomposed to precomposed UTF-8:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Encode qw/decode_utf8 encode_utf8/;
use Unicode::Normalize;

while (<>) {
    print encode_utf8( NFC(decode_utf8 $_) );
}
```

Usage:

```
perl compose.pl < decomposed.txt > composed.txt
```

Perl has also the `-i` option to modify a file “in situ”:

```
perl -i compose.pl file.txt
```

#### uconv

(Found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90164/424216) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.) `uconv` is not part of macOS, but can be installed from Homebrew (`brew install icu4c`) or Macports (`port install icu`).

Usage:

```
uconv -x any-nfc < decomposed.txt > composed.txt
```

#### Swift

If you have Xcode installed on your computer then a simple Swift script does the trick:

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift

import Foundation

while let line = readLine() {
    print(line.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping)
}
```

Usage:

```
swift compose.swift < decomposed.txt > composed.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.  Immediate issue solved, but I'll look at all the others (including Tom Gewecke’s suggestion).  Beats feeding perl a script containing a substitution for every possible combination!

Answer (score 2):

A MacOS app which can do these kinds of conversions is [UnicodeChecker](https://earthlingsoft.net/UnicodeChecker/).  It creates various Services that you can access when you select text in a document.

Comment: I may already have that.  If not, I'll get it.  The MacOS-include `iconv` does the job if the file is small.  (And already did for this incident.)

Answer (score 0):

BBEdit has a 'Precompose Unicode' command in its Text menu. There is also an AppleScript command of the same name in the app's AS library.