# Mac converting to roman letters with diacritical marks automatically

Tags: keyboard, filesystem, language

All files on my mac has had åäö converted to aao with equivalent diacritical characters (so they look exactly like åäö but are in fact combinations of "a" and a diacritical mark that looks like "°", etc.)

How can I change this behavior in mac so that the original letters are retained? I alternate between English and Swedish keyboard layout, but even when on Swedish (which has åäö natively), filenames are converted in a matter of seconds to aao with diacritical marks.

Comment: What's your goal here?  (AIUI, the characters should be [directly equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) — looking and behaving the same in both cases.  So for example it shouldn't matter whether you have U+00F1 (LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE), or U+006E (LATIN SMALL LETTER N) followed by U+0303 (COMBINING TILDE); the results should be the same.)

Comment: Why do you need this exactly?

Comment: I have a script that automatically transcribes audio files whenever they are put in a certain folder. The filename of the audio file is used as a sort of key throughout the process (storing transcriptions by other models, assigning metadata, etc). Weird errors kept occurring because, I suppose, my scripts converted "ö" back to the original "ö" in some stages and then "ö" == "ö" resolved False, yielding errors. My initial thought was that converting the error to the "ö" was the fault, but based on your all's input, I suppose I'll look for whatever is changing ö back to ö and eliminate that.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t change this behavior as far as I know.  Apple file names are always in decomposed form.  See this earlier question

[What the difference and usage of encodings UTF-8 and UTF-8-MAC in iconv?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346453/what-the-difference-and-usage-of-encodings-utf-8-and-utf-8-mac-in-iconv)